# Simulate isTrusted=true to an event listener (mouseEvent)

Tags: javascript

This is a similar question to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073710/is-it-possible-to-simulate-istrusted-true), although that question doesn't have a marked answer and isn't very specific.

I am simulating a click using a `mouseEvent`:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {...}));
```

and I have a  listener:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Is is possible for me to simulate/spoof `isTrusted=true` to that listener?

Comment: First thing I'd try would be to try to assign to the `isTrusted` property of the event and see what happens?

Comment: How much you could trust to a trust indicator if it was programmable ..?

Comment: @CertainPerformance According to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) it is read-only, which explains why when I tried doing this the listener still showed the event as `isTrusted=false`. I am only really asking this as the comment on the other post mentioned that it is possible to simulate this to a listener.

Comment: @Teemu So are you saying that it would be impossible to simulate this to an event listener?

Comment: Something like that. You can ofcourse attach the event to an exisiting function (instead of the anonymous) and make a regular call to that function without the real or dispatched event, when you can pass what ever you want.

Comment: @Teemu I'll give this a try. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be tweakable from my fiddling. Can't assign to non-configurable property, and I'd thought you might've been able to use `Object.create` and create a new object inheriting from `MouseEvent` with an `isTrusted` property, but that doesn't work either, `Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.`